# How to import data with row and column headers

Tags: matlab, matrix, dataset

I want to import data from a text file with row and column headers, and it in a matrix. For instance, the input file looks as follows:

```
data c1 c2 c3 c4
r1   1  2  3  4
r2   5  6  7  8
```

Also, is it possible to access the row and column names with the corresponding data element? And is it possible to modify that based on the result of operations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `textscan` with an extra `%*s` in the format string to gobble up the first header column in each row. The first header row should be used to count the number of columns, in case it is unknown:

```
fid = fopen('input.txt');  %// Open the input file

%// Read the first header row and calculate the number of columns in the file
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 1, 'Delimiter', '\n', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true);
cols = numel(regexp(C{1}{1}, '\s*\w+'));

%// Read the rest of the rows and store the data values in a matrix
C = textscan(fid, ['%*s', repmat('%f', 1, cols - 1)]);
A = [C{:}];                %// Store the data in a matrix

fclose(fid);               %// Close the input file
```

The data is stored in matrix `A`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it and successfully got my data stored in matrix but i have another doubt, If i need to know the column and row name of dataelement 3 (which will be r1,c3) how will i display that?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on `readtable` see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html

`T = readtable(filename, 'ReadVariableNames', true)` if the first column has the headers

or

`T = readtable(filename, 'ReadRowNames', true)` if the first row has the headers

You may also be interested into the `'HeaderLines'` name-value pair if you'd like to drop more than just the first line.

Comment: unfortunately this function was just introduced in Matlab 2013b.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that. The original question mentioned the command so I assumed that had a version with it.

Comment: @athypes Thanks for the response. since i am using 2013a i am not able to use the readtable option. My fault i dint mention it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `importdata`, for example, supposing the delimiter is "tab",

```
rawdata = importdata(filename, '\t');
row_names = rawdata.textdata(2:end,1);
col_names = rawdata.textdata(1, 2:end);
data_mat = rawdata.data;
```

The `row_names` and `col_names` are *cell array* types. If you like them to be one string delimited by `\t` or `,`, etc., you could use `strjoin` on them.